# ERROR Convirtiendo tipos de datos en SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Comienzo explicando mi problema, mi base de datos es un inventario y como tal tengo productos y categorias, asi que cada producto pertenece a una categoria diferente. Deseo realizar una consulta donde pueda contar el numero de productos que tiene cada categoria y a su vez seleccionar solo aquellas categorias que tienen menos de 3 productos en ella.
He conseguido hacer que se cuente el numero de productos por categoria de la siguiente forma:

```
SELECT  Categorias.Nombre_Categoria, count(Productos.Nombre_Producto) as 'Cantidad' FROM Categorias INNER JOIN Productos ON Categorias.ID_Categoria = Productos.ID_Categoria group by Categorias.Nombre_Categoria  order by Categorias.Nombre_Categoria
```

El problema es cuando quiero filtrar los resultados con la condicion de que se muestren solo las categorias con menos de 3 productos.
Lo he intentado de la siguiente manera agregando **WHERE**:

```
SELECT  Categorias.Nombre_Categoria, count(Productos.Nombre_Producto) as 'Cantidad' FROM Categorias INNER JOIN Productos ON Categorias.ID_Categoria = Productos.ID_Categoria where 'Cantidad' < 3 group by Categorias.Nombre_Categoria order by Categorias.Nombre_Categoria
```

pero inmediatamente me devuelve el siguiente error:

> *Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'Cantidad' to data type int.*

Deseo saber como puedo convertir los valores de la columna 'Cantidad' en enteros para que filtre los resultados de la consulta, o como poder realizar ***la consulta que cuente el numero de productos que tiene cada categoría y seleccione solo aquellos con menos de 3 productos.***

Espero me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Where` se usa cuando se necesita filtrar **antes** que `Group By` realice la agrupación.

Para filtrar **después** que el `Group By` realice la agrupación, se usa `Having`, que es el presente caso:

```sql
    SELECT Categorias.ID_Categoria, Categorias.Nombre_Categoria, count(Productos.ID_Producto) as 'Cantidad'
    FROM Categorias INNER JOIN Productos
    ON Categorias.ID_Categoria = Productos.ID_Categoria
    GROUP BY Categorias.ID_Categoria, Categorias.Nombre_Categoria 
        HAVING count(Productos.ID_Producto) < 3    --    <-- Solucion
    ORDER BY Categorias.Nombre_Categoria
```

Uso los `ID` porque me parece que es más rápido para el motor usar los números de `ID` en lugar del texto de los nombres.

---

Un ejemplo de filtro igual al anterior, pero antes que `Group By` realice la agrupación se presenta cuando se deben tener en cuenta sólo los productos cuyos nombres comiencen con la letra `A`:

```sql
    SELECT Categorias.ID_Categoria, Categorias.Nombre_Categoria, count(Productos.ID_Producto) as 'Cantidad'
    FROM Categorias INNER JOIN Productos
    ON Categorias.ID_Categoria = Productos.ID_Categoria
        WHERE Productos.Name LIKE 'A%'
    GROUP BY Categorias.ID_Categoria, Categorias.Nombre_Categoria 
    HAVING count(Productos.ID_Producto) < 3
    ORDER BY Categorias.Nombre_Categoria
```

Comment: Gracias me ha sido de mucha ayuda, excelente explicación. Saludos.